# How to calculate RSI14 in python the same way that the crypto exchanges are doing?

Tags: python, cryptography, ta-lib

I am trying to get a representative RSI14 indicator for my trading algorithm but this seems an impossible task. I have calculated it with 730 data points but even so, it is not the same as the exchanges. There is a clear offset due to the calculation mode I guess.

I've used ta-lib, tulipy and stockstats. Ta-lib and tulipy showd the exact same value, however stockstats showed a different one, still different than the crypto exchange though.

```py
    rsi = talib.RSI(data, timeperiod = 14)
    rsi = tulipy.RSI(data, timeperiod = 14)
    df['rsi'] = stock_df['rsi_14']
```

The RSI14 based on Kraken charts should be 49.08
Talib and tulipy show 42.08 (not always this -7 difference)
Stockstats showed a different value.

Comment: Do you know how RSI is calculated on exchange? For ex, as I heard, google finance calculate it from the beginning of the year.